# disable open ssh dialog for password during ssh session

Tags: python, ssh, openssh, nomachine-nx

Hi I am using NXclient (UNix/KDE) . I am running a python script where it is trying to create ssh session to another server and perform some automation task. Basically I am storing a password in variable and when SSH session asks for password I simply send the stored password. it work very well using putty.

PROBLEM:
when I use above nxclient. each time a SSH session needs a password 'A GUI prompt appears asking for password which freezes the terminal and fails my script . I do not want to enter password in gui because the password is already stored in a variable which will be used .

I have attached following screen shot. How can i disable this please help.
 [click for screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytLII.png)

[EDIT]
section of code which does that`if password_prompt:
               child.sendline(getpass.getpass('Enter your windows password: '))
           else :
               child.sendline(ssh_password)
           i = child.expect([os.path.basename(keyfile), pexpect.TIMEOUT])`

Comment: You could switch to the more secure [public/private key authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a few options:

1. Currently your keys are [added](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add) into [ssh-agent](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) with `-c` option which brings the confirmation dialog asking you to type `yes` each time a particular key is used. You may remove that `-c` option from your session startup scripts or change `ssh-agent` from the default OpenSSH Ssh-Agent to a more fancy (but perhaps less secure) variant which would allow you to store keys only for a session or somehow else etc
2. Completely disable usage of ssh-agent and supply the passphrase from terminal by `unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable. Be prepared that passphrases can't be read from STDOUT, they require usage of TTYs to handle input (check [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/))
3. Switch to passphrase-less keys. In case of keys dedicated to a robot this doesn't seem like a major secure breach owing to the fact that you're going to store the passphrase in plain-text. But probably it'd be better to configure

Comment: What do you mean by "Currently your keys are added into ssh-agent with -c option"  . Where is session startup script?

Comment: This depends on the distribution you currently use. Mine adds keys upon startup from a script in `/etc/profile.d/`

Comment: Or you may simply re-add the key without `-c` option to avoid unnecessary confirmation with `ssh-add`

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is another environmenmt variable called DISPLAY . unsetting both DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS helped me solve this